# How to migrate Doctrine in-memory database before PHPUnit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, doctrine-orm, doctrine, phpunit, doctrine-migrations

I'm using Doctrine DBAL and want to test (with PHPUnit) my repositories using an in-memory sqlite database. Since it is in-memory I need to run the migrations before the tests.

In Laravel you can do this easily by including the RefreshDatabase trait in your test class.

Before switching to the Doctrine DBAL I was using the Doctrine ORM and was able to set up the database from my tests as such:

```php
self::$entityManager = EntityManagerFactory::getEntityManager();

$metadatas = self::$entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
$schemaTool = new SchemaTool(self::$entityManager);
$schemaTool->updateSchema($metadatas);
```

I put this in some base `DoctrineORMRepositoryTestCase` class so that each individual repository test class inherited from it and the database was always setup before the tests ran.

I haven't found a way to do this with the Doctrine DBAL. I've tried running

```php
exec('/path/to/vendor/bin/doctrine-migrations migrate --no-interaction')
```

from my test class and I get the message `++ 1 sql queries` in the console which sounds like it has successfully migrated (I currently only have 1 migration class), but then all of my tests fail with the message `no such table...`.

How can I run my Doctrine DBAL migrations from my PHPUnit tests?